# App is crashing after Home is pressed. Unable to pause - Derived class did not call super.onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, super, illegalstateexception, android-homebutton

When I press the Home button, the app should be paused, save all state and work fine.
Instead I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   pause activity
>   {be.test.tester/be.test.tester.DataScreen}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Derived class did not call
>   super.onSaveInstanceState() at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3641)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3574)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:136)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2186)
>   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)
>
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Derived class did not call
>   super.onSaveInstanceState() at
>   android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:6087)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1207)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1207)
>   at
>   android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:6068)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1475)
>   at
>   android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1106)
>   at
>   android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1056)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1289)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3623)
>   ... 12 more

My activity reacts on touch:

```
public class DataScreen extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{
```

I'm getting some extra's from the intent:

```
totUsage = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("extraTotUsage"));
    limit = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("extraLimit"));
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mylist = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) bundle.get("extraMyList");
```

A custom view is showing data (canvas). When you scroll on screen, data changes in custom view (set, get method) and redraws itself.

I don't really manage the onSaveInstanceState here, don't really know if I have to.

My app is onTop of the stack, because of:

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I don't understand the error.

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that you are not calling inherited version of `onSaveInstanceState`. If you have overriden this method (and I'm not sure if you did, your wording is a bit unclear about that), you must have `super.onSaveInstanceState` called there.

Comment: I'm not overriding them. Not in costum view and not in the activity.

Answer (score 5):

You should override onSaveInstanceState and call its super method like shown below. At least it helped me with the same problem.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // your stuff or nothing
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // your stuff or nothing
}
```

Comment: If this solves the problem (with "nothing"), it seems to be evidence of a bug in android code.. I'd hate to say it, but it makes me worry about other faulty guarantees..

Comment: @snapfractalpop If you overload a method how else would it call the higher level code if you didn't then refer to the super method?!

Comment: @jamesakadamingo I meant by "with 'Nothing'" that the methods are effectively not overridden.

Comment: @snapfractalpop: but it helps. Unfortunately, I share your concern above.

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but I also had to add try { ... } catch (IllegalStateException e) { } around both of the super calls to get it working correctly.  Odd.

Answer (score 2):

I've just been dealing with this problem. In my app the main activity allows a second activity to be called to display info/instructions etc, it also has a surface view that draws the runtime element of the app.

The main activity has a variable to hold the surface view, if that variable hasn't been set before the info/instructions activity is called I get this error. I simply moved the surface view variable assignment into the main activity onCreate and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that one uses a custom preference (e.g. custom dialog preference) that does not call "super.onSavedInstanceState()" which leads to the same error.